# A Complicate sum with Mathematica, need Help!

Tags: summation, combinatorics

I found the sum shown below in a scientific paper. I need to calculate it.

$$\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_n=m}{m \choose k_1,\,k_2,\,\ldots,\,k_n}\ f_{k_1}(x)\,f_{k_2}(x)\,...\,f_{k_n}(x),\qquad k_i \in \mathbb{N} $$

where $f(x),m$ and $n$ are known.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: i have no idea how ill do that

Comment: Some specificity about $f_{k_i}$ would also help.  If $f_{k_i}(x)=p_i^{k_i}$, then the sum is $(p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n)^m$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

As an example with `m = 5`, `n = 3`, and `f[ki][x]` the functions in the question, the `Sum` can be written as

```
m = 5;
Sum[KroneckerDelta[m - (k1 + k2 + k3)] Multinomial[k1, k2, k3] 
    f[k1][x] f[k2][x] f[k3][x], {k1, m}, {k2, m}, {k3, m}]
(* 90 f[1][x] f[2][x]^2 + 60 f[1][x]^2 f[3][x] *)
```

See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html) for the definition of `Multinomial`.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting but i think isn't work ,
because KroneckerDelta[4 - (k1 + k2 + k3)] equals 0 in any case here,
but i have and idea from your code ,
i must write like that 

KroneckerDelta[ (k1 + k2 + k3),4]
that mean if k1+k2+k3=4 so i do the sum, Thank u @bbgodfrey

Comment: @TH3  You are misinterpreting the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerDelta.html) of `KroneckerDelta`.  See, in particular, the "Details" section.